# How to remove Oracle 10g from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, oracle-10g

I have to remove Oracle 10g XE from my PC.

It turned out to be far more complicated than I had thought: I couldn't find any suitable software products to remove from 'Add or Remove Programs'. I then started looking on the Internet and came across two options, which were a dead end for me:

1. **Via the Universal Installer** - I couldn't find such thing; can anyone help me figure out where should it be?
2. **Following guides like [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ManualOracleUninstall.php)** - should I really be manually removing keys from the registry? In 2011?

Answer (score 1):

The Universal Installer should be listed in your Start Menu unde: All Programs > Oracle > Oracle Installation Productions, or as setup.exe in a location similar to this (this is from 'real' Oracle rather than XE, but I believe this should get you close):

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\oui\bin\setup.exe
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I already searched those locations - no sign of setup.exe... I also searched the C:\oracle... directories for all *.exe files and I couldn't find any setup.exe.

Comment: Interesting. According to http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#CIHDDHJD, I was wrong and XE *should* actually be in the Add/Remove Programs control panel applet.

Comment: I know.. I've been using oracle 10g XE with Win XP and it used to be in Add/Remove Programs, but now with WIN 7 it is not there..